# Python SQLite insert with dynamic columns or use DEFAULT value

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I am working with flask-restful and a user can post some required and some optional data, which i would like to make an SQLite insert statement with. The problem is that i dont want to butcher the sql statement by using variables for column names and checking which argument is `None` and which has some data. I was hoping i could just use all columns and when arg2 or arg3 are `None`, the database would use the colums default values. Sadly i get the message `NOT NULL constraint failed: mytable.col1`. Removing `NOT NULL` from the table creation with my method will just insert NULL when using my statement.

Is there an explicit way to tell SQLite to use its default value?

If not, is there a more graceful way to get the default value instead of executing some table schema query?

If not and no other solution exists, what would be the most efficient way to butcher the sql statement?

```py
parser_post = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser_post.add_argument('arg1', type=str, required=True)
parser_post.add_argument('arg2', type=str)
parser_post.add_argument('arg3', type=str)
args = parser_post.parse_args()

# ... db init code

cur.execute("insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?)", 
(args['arg1'], args['arg2'], args['arg3']))
```

The table was created like this:

```py
sql = """CREATE TABLE mytable (
    PK_id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    col1        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    col2        TEXT DEFAULT "global" NOT NULL,
    col3        TEXT DEFAULT "global" NOT NULL)"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Why not just create a dict containing entries of "args" plus the default values for missing entries? This dict can then be used as basis for the parameterized SQL statement.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that would work but its repeating db-side values in client code :  easy to get out of synch.

Comment: @MichaelButscher plus the default values? That means i need to query them from the database table information somehow (because hardcoding them is a no-go), which is also not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fall back on the database-side default value is to NOT provide data for a particular column in the insert.

In that case, the server will insert the default value for that column.  If you did not specify a default value in the `CREATE TABLE` (or later ALTER TABLEs) than that default value is NULL (which corresponds to Python None).

However, since col2 **does** have a database-specified default, via `col2 TEXT DEFAULT "global" NOT NULL`, then not specifying `col2` in the insert will instead cause sqlite to use `"global"`.  Ditto `col3`.

You can build the query dynamically, to exclude columns with `None`, as long as you are careful with what you compose into the query string.

```
def prep_qry(args, colnames):
    """this query is secure as long as `colnames` contains trusted data
    standard parametrized query mechanism secures `args`"""

    binds,use = [],[]

    for colname, value in zip(colnames,args):
        if value is not None:
            use.extend([colname,","])
            binds.extend(["?",","])


    parts = ["insert into mytable ("]
    use = use[:-1]
    binds = binds[:-1]
    
    parts.extend(use)
    parts.append(") values(")
    parts.extend(binds)
    parts.append(")")

    qry = " ".join(parts)

    return qry, tuple([v for v in args if not v is None])

print(prep_qry([1,None,3], ["col1", "col2", "col3"]))
print(prep_qry([1,2,3], ["col1", "col2", "col3"]))
```

##### Output:

```
('insert into mytable ( col1 , col3 ) values( ? , ? )', (1, 3))
('insert into mytable ( col1 , col2 , col3 ) values( ? , ? , ? )', (1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: This should work because i could do `prep_qry(args.values(), args.keys())` right? Or does this seem insecure? Info: only arguments added through `parser_post.add_argument()` appear in `args`. The arg keys are the column names for simplicity and readability

Comment: Yup, feed this function with `colnames`= hardcoded colnames and `args` coming from the  parser_post.parse_args().  For extra paranoia, you could check the individual colnames for a match to sql column naming conventions, i.e. alphanumeric in ASCII, and `_`, pretty much.  regex "[a-z0-9_]+".  Check the entire colname fits, not just the start.  A lot of SQL injection happens around `'` single quote variables.

Comment: @Slluxx and... don't forget to accept/upvote **IF** it actually helps you.  Welcome aboard.

Comment: It worked flawlessly. Now i just need to adapt your script for update and delete statemenets. But thats outside of the scope of the initial question. Thank you very much!